# Split a sequence with conditions

Tags: list-manipulation, random, algorithm

I need a function which splits a **sequence of arbitrary length**

at `x` **random** points and which guarantees that each partition (bin) contains a **minimum** of `y` elements

```
RandomSplit[data_?VectorQ, x_Integer, y_Integer] := "?"
```

`TakeList` or `SequenceSplit` might be candidates to do this, but I don' t know how to get the partition lengths in a random manner and with the minimum binning size.

An **example** with 100 elements, 4 partitions and a minimum bin length of 10:

```
TakeList[Range[100], {10, 10, 70, 10}];
```

Or

```
TakeList[Range[100], {37, 21, 31, 10}];
```

But not

```
TakeList[Range[100], {5, 15, 50, 30}];
```

Comment: Try: `IntegerPartitions[100, {4}, Range[10, 100, 10]]` and `IntegerPartitions[100, {4}, Range[10, 100]]` to see if these meet your needs. The second one has `1906` entries.

Comment: `RandomChoice[IntegerPartitions[100, {4}, Range[10, 100]]]` is what I was looking for - please post this as an answer

Comment: you probably need `RandomSample@RandomChoice[IntegerPartitions[100, {4}, Range[10, 100]]]`?

Comment: Thank you, @kglr, that seems to work even better

Comment: Will `RandomChoice` not give a single value? Why use the `RandomSample` as well? @eldo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following will split the integer `100` into exactly four partitions, but with numbers restricted to multiples of 10.

```
IntegerPartitions[100, {4}, Range[10, 100, 10]]
```

> {{70, 10, 10, 10}, {60, 20, 10, 10}, {50, 30, 10, 10}, {50, 20, 20,
> 10}, {40, 40, 10, 10}, {40, 30, 20, 10}, {40, 20, 20, 20}, {30, 30,
> 30, 10}, {30, 30, 20, 20}}

---

The following will partition the integer `100` into four partitions and selects results such that `37` appears in each set at least once.

```
IntegerPartitions[100, {4}, Range[20, 100]] // 
 Cases[#, {___, 37, ___}] &
```

> {{37, 23, 20, 20}, {37, 22, 21, 20}, {37, 21, 21, 21}}

---

As another example the integer `100` can be divided using only the prime numbers:

```
primes = Table[Prime[i], {i, 1, PrimePi[100]}]
```

> {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 
> 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97}

```
IntegerPartitions[100, 2, primes]
```

> {{97, 3}, {89, 11}, {83, 17}, {71, 29}, {59, 41}, {53, 47}}

Comment: Thank you, @Syed, I've always regarded `IntegerPartition` as a number theory thing. Now I see that it can be useful in other contexts too.

Comment: @eldo You are most welcome.

Answer (score 3):

**FrobeniusSolve**

```
possibilities=Select[FrobeniusSolve[{1, 1, 1, 1}, 100],
    #[[1]]>=10 && #[[2]]>=10 && #[[3]]>=10 && #[[4]]>=10&];

RandomChoice@possibilities

(* {39,22,13,26} *)
```

```
Table[RandomChoice@possibilities,10]

(*{
   {42,10,29,19},
   {18,24,48,10},
   {17,37,17,29},
   {30,21,31,18},
   {17,14,43,26},
   {11,25,25,39},
   {41,19,24,16},
   {14,18,15,53},
   {37,22,19,22},
   {25,19,12,44}
  }*)
```

```
possibilities//Short

Length @possibilities

Length@FrobeniusSolve[{1, 1, 1, 1}, 100]

(* 

  {10,10,10,70},{10,10,11,69},<<39707>>,{69,11,10,10},{70,10,10,10}}

  39711 

  176851 

*)
```

Although this method is much less efficient that the `IntegerPartitions` method [posted](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/290093/106) by @Syed, and may even come under the heading 'just for fun', it does provide a random sample with a minimum bin length of 10.

For an integer range between 10-100, there are `39711` four-element partitions where the total of each partition is 100.

(For a range 0-100, there are `176851` four-element partitions with a total of 100, and *all* of these are initially generated by the `FrobeniusSolve` method).

**IntegerPartitions**

As shown by @Syed:

```
(pList=IntegerPartitions[100,{4},Range[10,100]])//Short


(* {{70,10,10,10},{69,11,10,10},<<1902>>,{26,25,25,24},{25,25,25,25} *)
```

```
Length@pList

(* 1906 *)
```

However, the elements in each sublist produced by `InterPartitions` are ordered highest-to-lowest. `{18,24,48,10}`, for example, is not present.

```
MemberQ[pList, {18,24,48,10}]

(* False *)
```

As pointed out by @kglr in a comment, calling `RandomSample` on a `RandomChoice` from `pList` solves this problem.

```
RandomSample@RandomChoice@pList

(* {38,25,22,15} *)
```

As most, but not all, of the elements of `pList` (those of the form
{a,b,c,d}) will produce 24 random samples, one would expect the total number of possibilities to be less than `1906x24 (45744)`. (I'm sure there is a way to mathematically calculate the value).

The `FrobeniusSolve` method produced a value of `39711` and the 'brute force' method can be used to check that calling `RandomSample` on the results of  `IntegerPartitions` generates an identical number of possibilities:

```
Length@Union@((Table[RandomSample[#], 
  1000]&/@IntegerPartitions[100,{4},Range[10,100]])//Catenate)

(* 39711 *)
```

```
Union@((Table[RandomSample[#], 1000]&/@IntegerPartitions[100,{4},Range[10,100]])//Catenate)//Short

    (* {{10,10,10,70},{10,10,11,69},<<39707>>,{69,11,10,10},{70,10,10,10}} *)
```